# Firebird sql remove milliseconds from query

Tags: sql, firebird

So I have this query:

```
SELECT FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD || ' ' || FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD 
FROM BANDZENDINGEN
```

which combines a date column with a time column, but I get this result:

[image]

as you can see I get milliseconds, but in the original column there are no milliseconds behind the time:

```
   SELECT FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD FROM BANDZENDINGEN
```

[image]

Why is this happening? and what can I do to remove the milliseconds?

Comment: What data type is `FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD`. And what does `'FT: '||FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD` return?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD data type is time. and SELECT 'FT: '||FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD FROM BANDZENDINGEN returns this                       FT: 07:01:56.1330

Comment: I assume that your SQL client simply doesn't display milliseconds for `time` (and probably `timestamp`) columns. But by concatenating them to a string value, the server (not your SQL client) converts the time value and apparently Firebird does include the milliseconds then

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your help, but how do I remove the miliseconds?

Comment: I don't know Firebird well enough, but you need to find a function that formats a time or timestamp value the way you need it. In Postgres this would e.g. be `to_char()`

Comment: tasks like data representation are better suited to the program that does the representation, makes the report, user interface, etc. Firebird is database server, its task is to keep data and the give it to the program with maximum accuracy. It is the program's task to turn that (binary!) data into any way that human can comfortably read. So, you have to setup your program that you made screenshot of, or maybe shoes different program, one that would allow you to show time in any format you may like

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name firebird has a bunch of string functions, so he can cut off last 5 letters, for example. Or any letters starting with last rightmost dot. It is just a wrong approach to making database-related programs.  http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem in my php file:

```
   $dateArr = array();
   $date = $sfm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

   foreach ($date as $row)
   {
      $new_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row));
      array_push($dateArr, $new_date);
   }
```

Comment: And that is THE way to go :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 
type date for FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD 
and type time for FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD

you can do something like this

```
select 
cast(FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD as date)||' '||substring(cast(FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD as time) from 1 for 8) 
FROM BANDZENDINGEN
```

Answer (score 1):

When you only query the time, the conversion to string is done by the client application. Here it apparently doesn't include the sub-second part. When you concatenate a time value to a string, then it uses locale-dependent conversion on the server, which does include the sub-second part (this may also be locale dependent!).

There are several possible solutions

1. Don't do concatenation, but format client-side

   - Instead of concatenating date and time as a string, use addition to form a timestamp, and then format client-side
   - Don't use separate fields, but a single timestamp field, and then format client side.
2. Use string manipulation functions

   - [`LEFT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-left): `LEFT(FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD || ' ' || FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD, 19)`
   - [`SUBSTRING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring) : `SUBSTRING(FD_DATUM_INGEVOERD || ' ' || FT_TIJD_INGEVOERD FROM 1 FOR 19)`
   - `SUBSTRING` with SQL regular expression (Firebird 3), but that is really overkill here

Formatting client-side is almost always the better choice.